# Making a table fullpage when using the twocolumn option

Tags: tables, two-column

I'm using the `twocolumn` option and `landscape` geometry to get two pages in one:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

I'd like to reserve one full landscape page for a big table. The table should occupy a whole page even if its dimensions are less than the page. How can I do that?

Comment: `\begin{table*}[p] ... \end{table*}` ?

Comment: @Zarko As far as I know the `p` option allows the table to overflow its column. I'd like, however, make it so that the table occupies a full page no matter what. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: actually, option `[p]` is meaning less since `figure*` always move figure on the top of the next pages. make image enough large (for example with adding margins or zero width rule with height of text) that it will occupy whole page. For more, you need to provide minimal working example (with dummy text and size of demo image (from `graphicx` package).

Comment: `[p]` does not make it overflow its column: it forces the float on to a float page which has no non floating text, Zarko's suggestion should answer your query.